# Не могу добавить CSS для Thymleaf

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Пишу MVC приложения на Spring Boot. Хочу проходить авторизацию и регистрироваться на своей странице. Добавляю к ней css файл из директории static.css, но ничего не происходит.
Пробовал писать th:href="@{...} но ничего не происходит.

[image: Пробую добавить css файл]

[image: Вид моих директорий]

---

**Solution**
Дал разрешение в SecurityConfig в методе securityFilterChain проводить запрос .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/media/**").permitAll()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в login.html вписал следующее в тег 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит путь моих директорий

Comment: Solution: Решение было следующим, сначало я дал разрешение Spring Security проводить запросы requestMatchers("/css/**", "/media/**").permitAll() и в login.html использовал следующий тег
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-reg-log.css" th:href="@{/css/style-reg-log.css}"/>